# How to define a Rails environment-specific class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, production-environment

I've got a class in Rails that is using factory girl which will not be defined in a production environment, so I need to only load the class if the environment is not production. I've tried using a simple return statement as seen below, but it returns an `Invalid return (SyntaxError)`:

```
return if Rails.env.production?
```

#### Additional Information

I'm using the [mail_view](https://github.com/basecamp/mail_view) gem. Here's the full error trace (only 1 line was printed):

```
mail_preview.rb: app/mailers/mail_preview.rb:1: Invalid return (SyntaxError)
```

Here's the relevant part of the file:

```
return if Rails.env.production?

class MailPreview < MailView
  include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  # ...
end
```

Comment: show the full error stack.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I've updated the question.

Comment: @ChristianDiLorenzo You could try placing the file elsewhere and then put the require statement in a conditional.  Or inside the class just include FactoryGirl (on initialization) when valid.  e.g. ` self.class.send(:include, FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods) unless Rails.env.production?`

Comment: @tgf I think what you suggested is the way to go. I was deploying this change to a staging server and it hastily blew up. Thank goodness for staging servers :-).

Comment: Is your staging server also using the production rails environment?  Some teams define specific staging environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do:

```
unless Rails.env.production?
  class MailPreview < MailView
    include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
    # ...
  end
end
```

Though then in your code you need to check if the constant exists. I'd rather leave it open, and do a check in your controller or model or wherever if it's production, use this class.

Comment: Hmm... I understand that this would work but would prefer not to wrap the entire class in an `if` block.

Comment: You can't return from a non method block though. You have to do it this way. or as i said, conditionally check where you use the class.

Comment: This actually blew up on a staging server so I'm going to try and put the file  elsewhere and require it conditionally.